# Where can I find the right combination for these pillars in Shroud Hearth Barrow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in Shroud Heart Barrow and encountered the infamous pillars, but I have no idea where the solution is to be found.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to continue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this video from youtube: [Shroud Hearth Barrow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBdugVWl5bI&feature=related). The interesting part starts around 6:00. The door from the screenshot seems unlocked, and in the room behind that door is the answer. The right combination from left to right is: "Whale, Hawk, Snake, Whale". This will lower the bridge.

Comment: I did the same thing as the asker: I assumed the door was locked and didn't bother trying to open it.

Answer (score 2):

Go through door at the top of ramp. Kill that guy. Stand on activation trigger. All the stones will start to rotate. Keep stepping on the activator until all symbols can be seen. Only one symbol can be seen at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a body on top of the trigger which drops the bridge, the bridge won't drop.  Try using shout to move any bodies off of the trigger if the bridge won't drop even with the correct combination.

Answer (score 0):

Dolphin, Eagle, Snake, and Dolphin.

You can find the clue when you enter that door in front of you in the screenshot. Just step on the circular platform and the cover to each door will be revealed.

You can find more details in this video.

Comment: That's a 20 minute video.  If you're going to link to Youtube, at least link to the relevant part of the video.

Comment: @fbueckert That still doesn't make the answer not useful. This answer also explains a lot more than the other ones

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to this room. There's a chain on the bottom level of the room, it opens a useless portcullis into a room on the stream. That portcullis has to be Closed before the bridge will come down!

Answer (score -1):

> Whale Hawk Snake Whale

That is the correct combination. Also, beyond the door, watch out because it's like lair of Draurgs and Skeletons. The big guy is the last one at the top.

Answer (score -3):

The correct combination is "fish bird snake fish", going from left to right.

Comment: This answer doesn't contribute anything new.